# Null Pointer Error after generating huffman code using recursive call to a function but it is not keeping the NULL value

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, struct

I was trying to generate huffman code for the input:

```
testcases=1
string s=abcdef
frequency={5 , 9 ,12 ,13 , 16, 45}
```

I was trying to traverse through pointers.
I am not sure if there is some error in copying the struct containing pointers because on printing the string it works fine for the nodes containing {12 and 13}
But it does not go back to the next node  once it gets to node 5

```
// { Driver Code Starts
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

 // } Driver Code Ends


struct Node{
    int index,frequency;
    Node *left,*right;
};
struct comp{
    bool operator()(Node const &a,Node const &b){
        if(a.frequency == b.frequency)
            return a.index > b.index;
        return a.frequency > b.frequency;
    }
};
class Solution
{
    vector<Node> tree;
    public:
        void give_me_codes(Node *root,vector<string> &ans,string s,int &size){
            cout<<"Printing s to show call: "<<s<<'\n';
           /*while(root!=NULL){
                cout<<root->index<<" "<<root->frequency<<"\n";
                root=root->right;
                root=root->left;
            }*/
            if(root==NULL){
                return;
            }
            if(root->index<size)
                ans.push_back(s);
            if(root->left!=NULL)give_me_codes(root->left, ans,s+"0",size);
            if(root->right!=NULL)give_me_codes(root->right,ans,s+"1",size);
        }
        vector<string> huffmanCodes(string S,vector<int> f,int N)
        {
            // Code here
            priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, comp> heap;
            for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
                Node element={.index=i,.frequency=f[i],.left=NULL,.right=NULL};
                heap.push(element);
            }
            
            int sz = heap.size();
            /*for(int i=0;i<sz;++i){
                Node ele = heap.top();
                heap.pop();
                cout<<ele.index<<" "<<ele.frequency<<"\n";
            }*/
            Node *root;
            int i=0;
            while(heap.size()>1){
                Node l = heap.top();heap.pop();
                Node r =heap.top();heap.pop();
                tree.push_back(l);
                tree.push_back(r);
                Node _new = {.index=sz++,.frequency=l.frequency+r.frequency,.left=&tree[i++],.right=&tree[i++]};
                root =&_new;
                heap.push(_new);
            }
            //cout<<tree[4].left<<" "<<tree[4].frequency<<'\n';
            //cout<<tree[2].left<<" "<<tree[2].frequency<<'\n';
            //tree[0].left=tree[0].right=NULL;
            //tree[1].left=tree[1].left=NULL;
            tree.push_back(*root);
            vector<string> ans;
            give_me_codes(root,ans,"",N);
            cout<<'\n';
            vector<string> v(N,"A");
            return ans;
        }
};

// { Driver Code Starts.
int main(){
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while(T--)
    {
        string S;
        cin >> S;
        int N = S.length();
        vector<int> f(N);
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            cin>>f[i];
        }
        Solution ob;
        vector<string> ans = ob.huffmanCodes(S,f,N);
        for(auto i: ans)
            cout << i << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}  // } Driver Code Ends
```

I tried assiging the left and right pointers of node 5 to NULL but it doesn't makes any difference and the output (when I print string s) stops after printing 110000 although I am expecting it to print 1100 and then probably move to the next node.

I shared the whole code and you can see what the output is showing. Can anyone please explain what is wrong here and what could be the possible fix?

Comment: why_is_your_title_full_of_under_scores_instead_of_spaces?

Comment: What an odd question title - underscores instead of spaces - why?

Comment: Also `root =&_new;` turns `root` into a dangling pointer, as `_new`'s lifetime is inside the `while` loop

Comment: Also the `left` and `right` pointers you store inside `_new` can potentially end up dangling, when `tree` needs to reallocate due to `push_back`s

Comment: so how should I then deal with left and right pointers when I am trying insert a similar node into the vector .... Is that probably why the recursion fails at node 5 because it's left and right pointers are not pointing to NULL anymore?